# Returning multiple results from multiple joins across several tables using mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

OK, I'm in over my head trying to do  multiple joins involving 3 tables. Just trying to return the title, author and text for a story after being passed the story id (SID) in the URL to this page. Basically I am trying to return the story title, the story author and the text. So far, only the story title is working in this code.

The script is being passed the story ID (SID) and I am trying to use that to get the author name and text of the story in addition to the story title which does work.

Here are the 3 tables:

```
user_meta table which has ID, display_name
stories table which has ID, SID, story_name
writing table which has SID, text
```

Here is the code so far (again, only title works so far after getting SID passed in the URL)

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// get the SID
$the_SID = ( isset( $_GET['writing'] ) ) ? $_GET['writing'] : false;


$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID, stories.story_name,
writing.text
FROM stories
LEFT JOIN writing ON stories.SID = writing.SID
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE stories.SID = $the_SID");
?>

Title: <b><?php echo $results[0]->story_name ?></b>
<p>
by: <em><?php echo $results->display_name ?></em><br />
<p>
<?php echo $results->text ?>
```

I know there will sql injection issues, but for now I am just trying to learn how to return these 3 variables with multiple joins across 3 tables. It's tricky enough to make sense of what should join to what and where let alone my actual code structure which I know is faulty above.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: The query command you are looking for is called inner join or join left/right

Comment: Sadly I have no idea what this is: DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle). The desired results though are to return Title: (whatever title)   Author (whoever wrote it)  and (the body of the text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Jargon

Just so you know the jargon: DDL is *Data Definition Language* -- the definitions of your tables. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is a really cool web site where you can muck around with SQL queries, and then post the links in things like StackOverflow questions.

### Answer to Question

If I understand your question correctly, given a particular `SID` value (Story ID assume), you want the story's author, title, and text.

You should indeed use a single query to get that information. I think this query will give you want you want:

```
SELECT u.ID. u.display_name,
       s.SID, s.story_name,
       w.text
  FROM stories AS s
  JOIN user_meta AS u ON s.ID = u.id
  JOIN writing AS w ON s.SID = w.SID
 WHERE s.SID = $the_SID
```

(Note: I've formatted this stuff so it's easy to see the SQL logic. You can put the line breaks wherever you please in your code.)

### Explanation

The trick here is to use `JOIN` operations to assemble the information from your different tables. The `ON` clause governs which rows in the table being JOINed are associated with each row in the first table.

This query starts with the `stories` table:

```
  FROM stories AS s
```

It then joins to the `user_meta` table by matching `ID` columns in those two tables. This is based on the guess that the `ID` columns identify users.

```
  JOIN user_meta AS u ON s.ID = u.id
```

Finally it joins to the `writing` table using the `SID` column:

```
  JOIN writing AS w ON s.SID = w.SID
```

### Commentary

You have some oddball queries in your example, that look like this next line. These are self-joins, in which you join a table to itself. Before trying to do that, you probably should master JOIN operations between different tables.

```
FROM writing LEFT JOIN writing ON stories.SID=writing.SID  /*probably wrong*/
```

You probably want this sort of thing because it makes more sense.

```
FROM stories LEFT JOIN writing ON stories.SID=writing.SID
```

To answer the question in your comment, most people using SQL to write software applications try to keep the number of queries down. They try to avoid writing PHP to use the results of one query to drive a second query. The idea is that the round trip from your PHP code to the MySQL server is something to minimize.  This is no hard-and-fast rule,  but it does help performance.

You mention part of the WordPress API in your question. You need to know that WordPress tables with names ending in `_meta` have more elaborate structures than what you've mentioned about your `user_meta` table. These queries may not work correctly if you're actually working with WordPress's `user_meta`.

Comment: Hi again Ollie. So I implemented your code which you can see cleanly in the original question where I edited the question to show the new implementation based on your feedback (sadly you can't use markup in these comments). The goodnews is that it still returns the title correctly and I have everything in one query. The bad news is that it still will not return the author name (display_name in wp_users table) or the text (text in the writing table). But I have a hunch we are very close...

Comment: Also, I do see how I'm getting this code gets the user's display name because there is no SID in the user's table. Is there something else I need to do to connect the stories table to the user's table to get the user's display name? Basically we need to user the SID to get the user's ID (called ID in stories) and then use that ID to connect to the user in the users table. Then I can get the user's name. But not sure how to do that or if you code does it?

Comment: Please see my edit. You probably should spend some time reading up on SQL at this point in your career.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading on SQL as I go. Not a career--just a fun hobby. My career is teaching English. Anyway, I don't get why I need to do "from stories AS stories" since I am not outputting a variable called stories anywhere. I did leave out the AS part of your code everywhere so I will go back and try with all the AS parts included. In your example under explanation you have "JOIN writing AS w ON s.SID = w.SID", but then you show the code under commentary without AS when you write "LEFT JOIN writing ON stories.SID=writing.SID"

Comment: These `AS x` items are aliases. They let you define shorthand result set column names and table names. When you do a `JOIN` of two different tables which happen to contain the same column names, you must disambiguate the column references. `AS x` lets you do that by mentioning `x.ID` rather than `table.ID`. It's like using pronouns to refer to people in a story, but with a scheme for defining which pronoun refers to which person.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Ok, so I implemented the code exactly as you suggested but now I get no results for any of the variables. I do follow your login and it seems like it should work. But even the title that was returning before no longer does with this code. At least I learned about aliases.

Comment: I am very pleased to report that your answer was perfect Ollie! The only reason is wasn't working is that the results return in an array, so I figured out that I needed to add [0] after results for all 3 result echoes such as this <?php echo $results[0]->text ?>. Thanks a million!